# Gathering values to a list from each df in grouped_df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df`:

| spell_num | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 4 | 18 |
| 4 | 19 |
| 4 | 20 |

and I want to get the `new_df`, with unique values in `spell_num` column and values from the `id` column collected in a list:

| spell_num | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | list(15) |
| 2 | list(16,17) |
| 3 | list(14) |
| 4 | list(18,19,20) |

I tried this code:

```
  new_df <- df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(spell_num) %>%
    dplyr::group_map(~gather_ids) %>%
    dplyr::slice(1)
```

where `gather_ids` is a function:

```
gather_ids <- function(x) {
  result <- x %>%
    dplyr::mutate(ids_lst = as.list(x$id))
  result
}
```

but it didn't work. Can you help me get the desired output either by helping to improve this code or suggesting a better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(spell_num) %>% 
  summarise(id = list(list(ID)))
```

**Output**

```
spell_num   ID
1           list(15) 
2           list(16:17) 
3           list(14) 
4           list(18:20)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(spell_num = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), ID = c(15L, 
16L, 17L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I ran your code and got this error: `object 'id' not found`. I think that R doesn't know where `id` in `list(id)` comes from...

Comment: @MartynasVenckus Can you try running it with the `dput` data in my answer now. I'm thinking that it does not like `id` since that is a deprecated/defunct function from `plyr` and `dplyr`.

Comment: There was an issue on my side, I got this sorted now. I am accepting the answer. Thank you very much!